# Create a page without adding a page in the Database

Tags: pages

I am trying to include a special Archive page with my theme, right now I have a PHP file with

`Template Name: Archives Template` at the top and I the user must create a blank archive POST PAGE and then select this as the template.

The content for creating the page is blank so nothing is added into the database for the page content.  Is there anyway to make it where they do not have to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get an archive for a custom post type?

Comment: No archive was just used for an example, I am trying to add a page to a theme without making the user add a page to the DB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To wit, this technically isn't a 'page', however it's a way to surface content using mod_rewrite. The goal here is to add a URI segment of foobar that will trigger a custom query, then include the specified template file.

Add a rewrite rule:

```
add_action('init', 'foo_add_rewrite_rule');
function foo_add_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^foobar?','index.php?is_foobar_page=1&post_type=custom_post_type','top');
    //Customize this query string - keep is_foobar_page=1 intact
}
```

See the [WP_Query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more information about customizing the query string.

Register a new query var:

```
add_action('query_vars','foo_set_query_var');
function foo_set_query_var($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'is_foobar_page');
    return $vars;
}
```

Force WP to select your page template:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'foo_include_template', 1000, 1);
function foo_include_template($template){
    if(get_query_var('is_foobar_page')){
        $new_template = WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/themes/your-theme/template-name.php';
        if(file_exists($new_template))
            $template = $new_template;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Flush the rewrites by visiting Settings->Permalinks, then visit http://yourdomain.com/foobar

Comment: :) Glad to help.

Comment: I've tried this and it works, but one issue I'm having is that it ends up being a front page/ home page and I'd like it to be a 'single'. Know of any way of adjusting this?

Answer (score 2):

An additional remark to Brian Fegter's answer. if you want to flush the rewrites rules programmatically instead of visiting Settings->Permalinks, you can use `flush_rewrite_rules()`.

However, don't put it on `init` hook, as the Wordpress Codex strongly recommands. You can put both `flush_rewrite_rules()` method and the `foo_add_rewrite_rule()` on `register_activation_hook`.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_flush_rewrites' );
function myplugin_flush_rewrites() {
add_rewrite_rule('^foobar?','index.php?is_foobar_page=1&post_type=custom_post_type','top');
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to stop the `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` functions from evaluating to true for my "fake" page by adding a `pre_get_posts` method

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_pre_get_posts', 1 );
function foo_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // check if the user is requesting an admin page 
    // or current query is not the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ){
        return;
    }

    // edit the query only when we are dealing with our "fake" pages
    // if it isn't, return
    if ( get_query_var('is_foobar_page') ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'page');
        $query->is_home = false;
    }

}
```