# Clean URLs for custom $_GET variables

Tags: rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I have a query var `show=othertemplate` that I can add to any URL to show any post, page or archive in Wordpress in a different template, like this: **mysite.com/[any URL]/?show=othertemplate**.  I'd like for it to be accessible via clean URL, like **[any URL]/othertemplate** or **[any URL]/show/othertemplate**.

I have tried achieving this by registering the query var with a query_vars filter and adding code like below to .htaccess, but Wordpress intervene and throws a 404. WP Debug Bar says that the query is looking for attachment=print.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/othertemplate/?$ /index.php/$1?view=othertemplate [L]
```

I have also tried using the Wordpress rewrite functions, but the same thing happens.

```
function st_myqueryvars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'show';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'st_myqueryvars');

function st_myrewriterules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $newrules = array();
  $new_rules['^(.*)/othertemplate/?$'] = 'index.php/$matches[1]?show=othertemplate';
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules','st_myrewriterules');
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

> **Update:** After flushing permalinks I see that this WP function rewrites **/*[any URL]*/template** to **index.php?show=template** instead of
>   **index.php?*[the URL's corresponding query string]*&show=template**. I
>   can't 'hard code' a query string like
>   post_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]... into the rewrite rule
>   because it needs to work for any page/post/archive, which have different permalink structures. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at "Rewrite Endpoints", which are much simpler to work with than custom rewrites. And they fit your use case perfectly: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint

You might add your "show" endpoint like so:

```
function wpsx_37961_add_endpoints() {

    // Add the "show" rewrite endpoint to all URLs
    add_rewrite_endpoint('show', EP_ALL);

}
add_action('init','wpsx_37961_add_endpoints');
```

Then you can check for its value on the WP action (or maybe earlier, I'm not sure), like:

```
function wpsx_37961_check_endpoint() {

    $show = $wp_query->get( 'show' );

    // Now, do whatever template switching you want based on the $show var's value

}
add_action('wp','wpsx_37961_check_endpoint');
```

The work of actually switching templates is up to you, but this gets your endpoints in place. No filtering query vars, no hacking together rewrite rules, no tough stuff :)

Comment: This looks useful! I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37644/create-a-page-without-adding-a-page-in-the-database/37649#37649). This should help you along your way. You're on the right track. Once you add a rewrite rule, remember to flush the perms by visiting Settings->Permalinks

Comment: I forgot to flush rewrite rules, which is a start.  But now it rewrites `/[any URL]/template` to `index.php?show=template` instead of `index.php?[the URL's corresponding query string]&show=template`.  I can't 'hard code' a query string like `post_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]...` into the rewrite rule because it needs to work for *any* page/post/archive.

Comment: any suggestions for a rewrite rule that will work for any permalink, including multiple CPTs/taxonomies?