# $paged always 0 on plugin's custom page

Tags: plugin-development, query, paged

I'm making a plugin that loads a specific template depending on a certain query var being passed, in effect creating a page for the plugin on the front end, as outlined in this post:

[Create a page without adding a page in the Database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37644/create-a-page-without-adding-a-page-in-the-database) - the first answer by Brian Fegter

So if I head to mysite.com/foobar I can use my custom template. However, if I hook a function up to wp_head and print out the paged query_var, it always returns 0, regardless of the value in the url (mysite.com/foobar/page/2, or example).

Any thoughts as to why this is happening? Is there a better way for my plugin to create a new page on the front end?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this myself. The problem being:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^foobar?','index.php?is_foobar_page=1','top');
```

Which prevents any other query_vars from being created. To resolve this, a slightly more complicated rewrite rule combo is set up:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^foobar?$','index.php?is_foobar_page=1','top');
add_rewrite_rule('foobar/page/([0-9]+)?$','index.php?is_foobar_page=1&paged=$matches[1]','top');
```

This takes into consideration the creation of the plugin's subpage 'foobar' and also allows for pagination within this page.

Hope this helps someone.