# Use page-templates without creating theme

Tags: php, pages, wp-admin

I have created 7 pages that are used for CPT and other information. I want to know if there is a way to call the page templates without creating them.
I just want a more tidy interface for the user, because, he does not go well with computers. And if there are many pages, I think he will be confused.

More in depth, I want to create an anchor link that redirects to a page template without creating the page in the admin panel.

I tried with the redirect, it does not work.

I found this post:
[Is there a way to remove or hide individual pages on the Edit Pages screen?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53074/is-there-a-way-to-remove-or-hide-individual-pages-on-the-edit-pages-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Which works, but I find it a little strange to create and then hide. Also, it is 5 years old, and I wonder if there is any new solution.

Thanks

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you described what you want to achieve.

Comment: and edit your question to add this description in also adding examples

Comment: i edit it, I think it is pretty clear. What do you mean by "to add this description in adding examples "?