# How to display non-page / post content

Tags: plugin-development, page-template, routing

I have a custom made Twitter stream on my site.

I want to have a permalink for each tweet which would go to a page which would display only the tweet - no other content - surrounded by my custom theme.

Ideally I would get Wordpress to display a Page Template on a certain url (something like /tweet/<tweet_id>), but I don't want to create a Page because it will appear in the main menu.

I'm happy to write a plugin but my Google-fu is failing help me to figure out how to display just that plugin's content on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a Page and looked at how [Exclude Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/) hides them.

This is what I came up with (in `functions.php`):

```
add_filter('get_pages','mytheme_exclude_pages');

function mytheme_exclude_pages ($pages)
{
    $showPages = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page)
    {
        if (!in_array($page->post_name, array('no-show', 'shy-page')))
        {
            $showPages[] = $page;
        }
    }
    return $showPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a "fake page" so to speak, where instead of creating the page in your dashboard area under `Pages -> Add New` then selecting a template from **Page Attributes** or by creating a template that matched the slug or id such as `page-{slug}.php` or `page-{id}.php` you instead use a combination of rewrite rules combined with hooking onto an action `template_redirect` to achieve the desired result.

You can see an exact example of this in my [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67732/setting-a-custom-sub-path-for-blog-without-using-pages/69147#69147) to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67732/setting-a-custom-sub-path-for-blog-without-using-pages/69147#69147).

I'll copy in my snippets below but the full explanation should be read in my answer above.

Step 1:

```
add_action('init', 'fake_page_rewrite');

function fake_page_rewrite(){

    global $wp_rewrite;

    //set up our query variable %fake_page% which equates to index.php?fake_page= 
    add_rewrite_tag( '%fake_page%', '([^&]+)'); 

    //add rewrite rule that matches /blog/page/2, /blog/page/3, /blog/page/4, etc..
    add_rewrite_rule('^blog/page/?([0-9])?','index.php?fake_page=blog&paged=$matches[1]','top');  

    //add rewrite rule that matches /blog
    add_rewrite_rule('^blog/?','index.php?fake_page=blog','top');

    //add endpoint, in this case 'blog' to satisfy our rewrite rule /blog, /blog/page/ etc..
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'blog', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );

    //flush rules to get this to work properly
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}
```

Step 2:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'fake_page_redirect');

    function fake_page_redirect(){

        global $wp;

        //retrieve the query vars and store as variable $template 
        $template = $wp->query_vars;

        //pass the $template variable into the conditional statement and
        //check if the key 'fake_page' is one of the query_vars held in the $template array
        //and that 'blog' is equal to the value of the key which is set
        if ( array_key_exists( 'fake_page', $template ) && 'blog' == $template['fake_page'] ) {

            //if the key 'fake_page' exists and 'blog' matches the value of that key
            //then return the template specified below to handle presentation
            include( get_template_directory().'/your-template-name-here.php' );

            exit;

        }
    }
```

Note: Some tweaking might be necessary to associate individual tweet IDs but we'd need to see your code that relates to the tweets.

These snippets go into your `functions.php` file. Naturally you should change any of the parameters that should otherwise meet your desired **end point**. So  where you see `blog` becomes `whatever-you-want` etc. The template name in the second snippet should correspond to your desired template.

Comment: Flushing the rules on `init` is evil.

Comment: Do it one time only. Then go say 10 hail marys.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for a less hacky solution. I eventually gave up and accepted I would have to make a page and looked at how Exclude Pages hides them.