# Template redirect template loaded, but the header 404

Tags: 404-error, post-status, template-redirect

I've created a template redirect for a given url, ex.: test.com/test

Test is page is not exists, i'm just checking the url from query_vars, if its match, i load the template with

```
include(file.php);
exit;
```

**The page loads and show what i expect, but the title is Page not found.** I solve this with a filter, but i saw that the whole page comes with a 404 status. Btw i saw that the builtin multisite activation message also has a 404 header. (I'm working on localhost.)

How can i solve this without creating the page itself in wp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially trying to create a "fake" page without having to create a physical page in the WordPress database and for that, you will need custom re-write rules.

For more details see my answer here: **[Setting a custom sub-path for blog without using pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67732/setting-a-custom-sub-path-for-blog-without-using-pages/69147#69147)**

Quick overview:

### step 1: setup your custom rewrite rules

```
add_action('init', 'fake_page_rewrite');

function fake_page_rewrite(){

    global $wp_rewrite;
    //set up our query variable %test% which equates to index.php?test= 
    add_rewrite_tag( '%test%', '([^&]+)'); 
    //add rewrite rule that matches /test
    add_rewrite_rule('^test/?','index.php?test=test','top');
    //add endpoint, in this case 'test' to satisfy our rewrite rule /test
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'test', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
    //flush rules to get this to work properly (do this once, then comment out)
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}
```

#### Step 2: properly include a template file on matching your query variable,

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'fake_page_redirect');

function fake_page_redirect(){

    global $wp;

    //retrieve the query vars and store as variable $template 
    $template = $wp->query_vars;

    //pass the $template variable into the conditional statement and
    //check if the key 'test' is one of the query_vars held in the $template array
    //and that 'test' is equal to the value of the key which is set
    if ( array_key_exists( 'test', $template ) && 'test' == $template['test'] ) {

        //if the key 'test' exists and 'test' matches the value of that key
        //then return the template specified below to handle presentation
        include( get_template_directory().'/your-template-name-here.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but I guess you can simply check against the return value of `get_query_var( 'test' )`. Another thing you could do is to check for the template using `locate_template()`.

Comment: Mod answer mate :)

Comment: No time for this - need to save the world first :)

Comment: A few years late but just wanted to chime in here.  While you can use the `template_redirect` action it can cause problems for any other WP functionality that needs to run after that hook.

It is better to use `template_include` filter and swap out the page template using that filter instead.

Comment: @bgallagh3r better late than never... This can be true in some instances. If you have a specific example however, where a known conflict may arise that cannot be sorted out by hook priority alone, feel free to suggest an edit so we can include some additional context for all to see.