# How to Change the path of a child page?

Tags: pages

I am displaying the list of child pages of the current page. but at one child page i want to give a path to pdf. how can it be possible? Please help.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
        'child_of'     => get_the_ID(),
        'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
        'depth'        => 0,
        'sort_column'  => 'ID',
        'sort_order'   => 'ASC',
        'title_li'     => ''
        ); ?>
   <?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>
```

output is-

```
 **current page**
    child page1
    child page2
    child page3 (..it should be link to pdf..)
    child page4
    child page5
```

Please help me to find out the solution?

Comment: Here is a similar [link][1]  which might solve your problem.

  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67732/setting-a-custom-sub-path-for-blog-without-using-pages

Answer (score 0):

```
$mypages = get_pages( array(
    'parent'     => get_the_ID(),
    'sort_column'  => 'ID',
    'sort_order'   => 'ASC',
    );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
          // Modify this line to include ID of page where want to change the link 
      if ($page->ID == $ID_OF_PAGE_THAT_SHOULD_BE_PDF_LINK) {
          // Modify this line to include your PDF link
          echo '<li><a href="YOUR_PDF_LINK_HERE">' . $page->post_title . '</a></li>';

      }
      else {
          echo '<li><a href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) .'">' . $page->post_title . '</a></li>';  }

     }
```