# Prevent 404 and serve custom template for custom URL

Tags: templates

In a nutshell what I want to achieve is this:

If slug equals `foobar` serve the `foobar.php` template.

I know I could do this with `page-foobar.php` but I don't want to create a page for this.

```
add_action('init', 'template_suggestions');
function template_suggestions() {

  global $wp;

  $current_slug = add_query_arg([], $wp->request);

  if ($current_slug == 'foobar') {

    // No, don't server the 404.php.
    // Serve foobar.php.
    // But how?
    // Big question mark.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! But this is a dirty thing. As it won't take care of pagination and underlying queries. If you need a bit more of WordPress' logic behind that custom route, please check the answer linked in the comments. But if you just need to serve one static page, this probably is a good starting point:

```
add_action('template_include', 'template_suggestions');
function template_suggestions($template) {

  global $wp;

  $current_slug = $wp->request;

  $foobar_template = locate_template(['foobar.php']);

  if ($current_slug == 'foobar' && $foobar_template != '') {

    // Prevent 404.
    status_header(200);

    return $foobar_template;
  }

  return $template;
}
```

Source [Don’t use template_redirect to load an alternative template file](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/)

---

Since I use Yoast I had to use `wpseo_title` instead of `document_title_parts` or `pre_get_document_title` to set the title accordingly.

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'template_suggestions_titles', 10, 1);
function template_suggestions_titles() {

  global $wp;

  $current_slug = $wp->request;

  if ($current_slug == 'foobar') {

    return 'Foobar';
  }
}
```

Comment: That `add_query_arg` is unnecessary. The slug is just $wp->request.

Comment: Is `/foobar` an actual Page, Post, Custom Post Type, Archive, etc? If not and this is a slug that has no underlying structure matching rewrite rules, you'd need to add a rewrite rule OR  you could `pre_get_posts` and `$query->is_404 = false`. Although you my need to do some other things to avoid any screwy data within the main query. Another option is for you to hook into `do_parse_request` and circumvent the main query and thus your `status_header(200)` should suffice. Or further down the request chain into `request` hook you can knock out the $query->query_vars['error']` value which is 404.

Comment: Right, I see now... You have no underlying object type. Take a look at another question to which I post an answer to achieve the very thing you are after here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/67732/13418

Comment: @userabuser – Yes, no underlying object. Do I really have to take care of so much more? I mean, I have a 200 status now, I have my template, it's just the page title that's missing and which doesn't seem to be settable via the usual hooks. Ah yeah, because I use Yoast and then that's `wpseo_title.`

Comment: Well.. not necessarily "all that". Hook into `pre_get_posts` or `request` or `do_parse_request` if you would like and alter the query var `$query->is_404 = false` (or whatever the accessible query vars are available to you). It's showing 404 because WP has set the 404 based on there being no rewrite. Buuut... if you are successfully returning a 200, just hook into `wp_title` and check for `$current_slug == 'foobar'` and filter the result based on that context. Dirty, but will do the job.